# Typeorm Database not starting?

Tags: node.js, express, typeorm

I bootstrapped typeorm with option init typeorm --database postgres --express.

I changed ormconfig to match my info in database.

[image]

There's no error. But it seems like nothing is running.

It seems that my database isn't the problem, as it does not throw the error.

Anything I am missing?

Below is the default setting

```
// index.ts 

import 'reflect-metadata';
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { Routes } from './routes';
import { User } from './entity/User';

createConnection()
    .then(async (connection) => {
        // create express app
        const app = express();
        app.use(bodyParser.json());

        // register express routes from defined application routes
        Routes.forEach((route) => {
            (app as any)[route.method](
                route.route,
                (req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) => {
                    const result = new (route.controller as any)()[route.action](
                        req,
                        res,
                        next
                    );
                    if (result instanceof Promise) {
                        result.then((result) =>
                            result !== null && result !== undefined
                                ? res.send(result)
                                : undefined
                        );
                    } else if (result !== null && result !== undefined) {
                        res.json(result);
                    }
                }
            );
        });

        // setup express app here
        // ...

        // start express server
        app.listen(8080);

        // insert new users for test
        await connection.manager.save(
            connection.manager.create(User, {
                firstName: 'Timber',
                lastName: 'Saw',
                age: 27,
            })
        );
        await connection.manager.save(
            connection.manager.create(User, {
                firstName: 'Phantom',
                lastName: 'Assassin',
                age: 24,
            })
        );

        console.log(
            'Express server has started on port 3000. Open http://localhost:3000/users to see results'
        );
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Comment: Paul, can you please elaborate on your statement "it seems like nothing is running"? Do you mean that your `console.log()` call never produces output?

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't config your database details. You have to add ormconfig file to your project.

Step 1 :- Create a file called ormconfig.ts in root directory.

Step 2:- Add these below code to that file and put your database details here.

```
{
  "type": "postgres", 
  "host": "localhost", 
  "port": 3306,
  "username": "root",
  "password": "",
  "database": "test",
  "synchronize": true,
  "entities": ["here put paths for your entities"],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to config your typeorm configurations using ormconfig file.